# How to handle promises in nested loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, promise

I have an array of objects like this:

results from an aggregate give me a result with same structure as follows:

```
results = [
  {id: 1, test: biology, candidates:[ {cid: 11},{cid: 12},{cid: 13}]},
  {id: 2, test: chemistry, candidates:[ {cid: 15},{cid: 16},{cid: 17}]},
  {id: 3, test: physics, candidates:[ {cid: 1},{cid: 6},{cid: 7}]}
];
```

So i need to loop in the array, then for each candidate call a promise function getTotalMarksPerCandidate(that has a Promise.all and resolve the variable after some computations). However, since looping in array, does not wait for promise to complete, I get promise...

Question: do you know how can i work this out so that when looping in my candidates array, it waits for results and continue? or any turnaround solutions?

So I map into the results array, then did a forEach in the candidates array, call the function getTotalMarksPerCandidate with the candidate object as parameter, push the result in a promise array. Then will resolve all promises received.

```
var new_Result = results.map( function (subject) {
 let promises = [];
 if (subject.candidates && subject.candidates.length > 0) {
  subject.candidates.forEach( (element) => {
   promises.push(mobileUtil. getTotalMarksPerCandidate(element));
  });
 }
 return Promise.all(promises).then( result => {
  console.log('Check this out', result);
  subject.newCandidatelist = result;
  return subject;
 });
});
console.log('R: ', new_Result);
resolve(params);
```

So in the return Promise.all(promises) callback function, I can see at that the promises are being resolved and i see the returning value from the function getTotalMarksPerCandidate. How can i do to set the new candidates object with the totalMarks to their respective parent object like

```
new_results = [
{id: 1, test: biology, candidates:[ {cid: 11, score: 88},{cid: 12, score: 90},
  {cid: 13, score: 91}]},
{id: 2, test: chemistry, candidates:[ {cid: 15, score: 91},{cid: 16, score: 91}, 
  {cid: 17, score: 91}]},
{id: 3, test: physics, candidates:[ {cid: 1, score: 91},{cid: 6, score: 91},
  {cid: 7, score: 91}]}
];
```

Thank you

Comment: Just use another `Promise.all` on the `new_Result`, which is an array of promises as well?

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this that is based solely on a nested `Promise` chain would be as follows:

```
/*
Obtain array of promises via results.map() and resolve each sequentially
*/
const new_Result = Promise.all(results.map((subject) => {

    /* 
    Start a promise chain for this subject 
    */
    return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {

        /* 
        Get candidates from current subject, or just an empty array if no valid candidates data present 
        */
        const candidates = Array.isArray(subject.candidates) && subject.candidates.length > 0 ? subject.candidates : [];

        /*
        Map candidates (if any) to this Promise.all() 
        */
        return Promise.all(candidates.map((candidate) => {
            return mobileUtil.getTotalMarksPerCandidate(element).then(function(score) {
                /*
                Assign the score returned from getTotalMarksPerCandidate() for current candidate object
                */
                candidate.score = score;

                /*
                Return the updated candidate to mapped array of promise results
                */
                return candidate;
            })
        }));
    })
    .then((result) => {

        console.log('Check this out', result);
        subject.newCandidatelist = result;
        return subject;
    });
}));
```

The key addtion here are these lines, which basically "attaches" the score value returned from the resolved promise of `getTotalMarksPerCandidate()` to the current `candidate` being iterated:

```
return mobileUtil.getTotalMarksPerCandidate(element).then(function(score) {

    candidate.score = score;

    return candidate;
})
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

With async/await the flow can be

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const new_Result = results.map(({ candidates, ...rest }) => {
            const updatedCandidates = candidates.map(async candidate => {
                const score = await getTotalMarksPerCandidate(candidate)
                return { score, ...candidate }
            })

            return  { candidates: updatedCandidates, ...rest }
        })

        console.log(new_Result)
    } catch(err) {
        // handle error
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dacre & Chridam & Bergi for taking the time to respond to this issue. So i tried both solutions and tweaked Dacre solution a bit and it worked and i got what i needed on my front end.

Params is a json object i passed as parameter to my function.
mobileUtil.getTotalMarksPerCandidate is a function being called, that return an object with the amended Marks in the object itself sent through as parameter initially.

```
Promise.all( results.map( jobtitle => {
                    return Promise.resolve()
                    .then(() => {

                        const candidates = Array.isArray(subject.candidates) && subject.candidates.length > 0 ? subject.candidates : [];
                        /*
                        Map candidates (if any) to this Promise.all() 
                        */
                       if (candidates && candidates.length > 0)
                       {
                            return Promise.all(candidates.map((candidate) => {
                                return mobileUtil. getTotalMarksPerCandidate(candidate).then( function(candidate) {
                                    /*
                                    Return the updated candidate to mapped array of promise results
                                    */
                                    return candidate;
                                })
                            }));
                       }
                    })
                    .then((result) => {
                        return subject;
                    });
                })
                ).then( res => {
                    params.listofnewCandidates = res;
                    resolve(params);
                });
```